# Does cloudera distribution of hadoop use the control scripts?

Tags: apache, hadoop, cloudera

Are the control scripts (start-dfs.sh and start-mapred.sh) used by CDH to start daemons on the fully distributed cluster?
I downloaded and installed CDH5, but could not see the  control scripts in the installation, and wondering how does CDH start the daemons on slave nodes?

Or since the daemons are installed as services, they do start with the system start-up. Hence there is no need for control scripts in CDH unlike apache hadoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as such, no. If I recall correctly, Cloudera Manager invokes the daemons using Supervisor (http://supervisord.org/). So, you manage the services in CM. CM itself runs agent processes as a service on each node, and you can find its start script in `/etc/init.d`. There is no need for you to install or start or stop anything. You install, deploy config, control and monitor servies in CM.

Comment: Thanks Sean! meanwhile i found that Cloudera uses init to configure the daemon services to start at the system start-up:  [link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_init_configure.html?scroll=topic_27_2). More over the installation does not has a step to enable password less SSH.

Comment: You can certainly install without passwordless SSH; it would be bad if you couldn't. CM can install given a root password, SSH key, or the same for a user who can sudo